# How can I create jQuery UI droppables recursively?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm using jQuery UI for drop and drag.

When the draggable item is dropped I use the drop function that appends a new HTML element and makes it draggable and droppable. It works in the first instance ( see http://jsfiddle.net/ze5zgfsq/1/ ) but the draggable + droppale features (including the drop functio) don't extend deeper than that.

I want it to work recursively, though, so that if another draggable element is dropped inside the created element (the dropped one) then a new draggable, droppable element is created within that and so on.

Here's the sample code:

```
$("#draggableObject").disableSelection();

$("#draggableObject").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: 0.7
});


$(".container").droppable({
    accept: "#draggableObject, .droppedObject",
    activeClass: "stateHighlight",
    hoverClass: "stateHover",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).append('<li class="droppedObject" style="color:black;text-align:center;">Dropped Object</li>');
        $(".droppedObject").draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: "clone",
            opacity: 0.7
        }).droppable({
            accept: "#draggableObject, .droppedObject",
            activeClass: "stateHighlight",
            hoverClass: "stateHover",
            greedy: true,
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).append('<li class="droppedObject" style="color:black;text-align:center;">Dropped Object</li>');
                $(".droppedObject").draggable({
                    revert: "invalid",
                    helper: "clone",
                    opacity: 0.7
                });

            }
        });

    }
});
```

And here's the HTML/CSS:

```
<ul>
    <li id="draggableObject">Draggable Object</li>
</ul>
<ul class="container">
    <li>Drop Items Here</li>
</ul>


ul {
    height: 300pt;
    width: 200pt;
    border: 1pt solid blue;
    border-radius: 2pt;
}
li {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100pt;
    min-width: 100pt;
    border: 1pt solid black;
    border-radius: 2pt;
    margin: 2pt;
    cursor: move;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question while trying to implement something similar.  See if this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/sdqfotqe/1/

The trick I used is to create the options object separately then use it inside itself i.e. $d.droppable(droppableOptions);

It doesn't do exactly what you are trying to do, but should help with the recursive side of things.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divItems">
    <div data-fhirq-type="group" class="editor-choice">Group</div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div data-fhirq-type="question" class="editor-choice">Question</div>
</div>

<br/><br />

<div id="divQuestionnaire">
    <div id="divRootGroup" class="editor-group"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.editor-group {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 50px;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    background: #efefef;
}

.editor-question {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 50px;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
    background: #677b92;
}

.editor-choice {
    cursor:move;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}

.droppable-hover {
    background: #fffa00;
}

.remove-choice {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#divGroupOptions').hide();
    $('#divQuestionOptions').hide();

    var droppableOptions = {
        accept: '.editor-choice',
        greedy: true, /* only drop the element in one place */
        hoverClass: "droppable-hover", /* highlight the current drop zone */
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            /* clone, because many elements can be added - it's a copy, not a move */
            $d = $(ui.draggable).clone();

            $d.removeClass('editor-choice');
            $d.addClass(($d.attr('data-fhirq-type') == 'group') ? 'editor-group' : 'editor-question');

            /* add a button so the element can be removed if no longer necessary */
            var $removeBtn = $('<button class="remove-choice">x</button>').click(function () { $(this).parent().remove(); });
            $d.append($removeBtn);

            /* make the new element droppable i.e. to support groups within groups etc... */
            $d.droppable(droppableOptions).sortable();

            $(this).append($d);
        }
    };

    $("#divRootGroup").droppable(droppableOptions).sortable();
    $(".editor-choice").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
});
```